# Loop through a list and call API in python

Tags: python, api, google-api

I have list of author names (more than 1k) and my google api quote limit is 20k I want to pass the author name into the API to get book informations. When I tested my code I got "429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url..." error, How can I slow down my running time without stopping the application. (I'm using Python in google colab )

```
author_List = ["J. K. Rowling", "mark twain","Emily Dickinson"] 
connGoogleAPI(author_List)
def connGoogleAPI(booksData):
  key= "**************************"
  books_list = []
  col= ['Title', 'Authors', 'published Date', 'Description','ISBN']
  books_list.append(col)  
  res = ""
  err = None
  with requests.Session() as session:
      #err= ""
      for Authors in booksData:
        params = {"q": Authors,"key": key,"maxResults": 1}
        delays = 65 # approximately 1 minute total delay time for any given author
        while True:
          try:
             #do something 
          except Exception as e:
              if err.status_code == 429:
                  #print("******")
                  if delays <= 0:
                      raise(e) # we've spent too long delaying
                  time.sleep(1)
                  delays -= 1
              else:
                  print("-----=")
                  raise(e) # some other status code     

   
        books_list.append(lookup(res,Authors))

  return books_list
```

Comment: Lists do not have a *to_dict* attribute

Answer (score 1):

you can `import time` and then add:

```
time.sleep(1)
```

at the end of your for loop, to pause for a second between each iteration.

Comment: That could slow things down unnecessarily. Better to wait until a 429 occurs then introduce a delay

Answer (score 0):

You could slow down your for loop like this:
first, you need to `import time`

```
delay = 2
for key in author_List:
   author = author_List[key]
   newList.append(searchData(author))
   time.sleep(delay)
```

The delay you can set a number how many seconds the loop gets delayed (here it would be 2 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want unconditional delays which will slow down your processing unnecessarily. On the other hand, if you start getting HTTP 429 you can't be sure when or even if the server is going to allow you to continue. So you need a strategy that only introduces delays when/if required but also doesn't get into an infinite loop. Consider this:

```
import requests
import time

listofauthors = ['Mark Twain', 'Dan Brown', 'William Shakespeare']

with requests.Session() as session:
    for author in listofauthors:
        params = {'q': author}
        delays = 60 # approximately 1 minute total delay time for any given author
        while True:
            try:
                r = session.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes', params=params)
                r.raise_for_status()
                print(r.json())
                break # all good :-)
            except Exception as e:
                if r.status_code == 429:
                    if delays <= 0:
                        raise(e) # we've spent too long delaying
                    time.sleep(1)
                    delays -= 1
                else:
                    raise(e) # some other status code
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I python in google colab doesn't recongise := so I put it in a separate variable however, I keep getting NoneType' object has no attribute 'status_code' and I've been trying to figure out the issue for 3 hr now (added extra number in key just to test the code and I updated the code in the main post)

Comment: I know nothing about Google Colab but the so-called "walrus" operator relies on Python version 3.7+. Having said that, the implication of what you've said is that session.get() is returning None and I don't think that's right. Can you edit your original question to show your updated code? In the meantime, I'll edit my answer for Python versions prior to 3.7

Comment: I edited the question , I didn't use session.get I used request.get insisted

Comment: Your edited code is not runnable. Try to copy/paste my answer and see what happens